# GoogleMaps Directions API limitations

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

In this document (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions?hl=en) Google explains that the limitations of the Directions API is set to 2500 requests by day, but I'm not specifying a key in the query (and can't locate a key field name in the query params).
How is Google calculating the limit? Exists this limit really?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Directions API probably goes by the requestor's IP address, since it does not require a Google Maps API key.

Comment: This is most likely true. When I used Google's reverse geocoding (also 2500 request limit/24h) I didn't need any key either.

Comment: Ok. If this is the case, I can have some clients that queries 2000 times/day without a problem. Correct? And also the service is free for the developer? In my API projects list Google is enumerating the requests total and the associated prize: 0.0$ Thanks again

Comment: @TheMatrix It shouldn't be a problem no. And yes, their services are free except if you're exceeding their limitations. Chances are, however, that if  you do provice an API key, they might see that your application is exceeding their limitations (queries * clients). I cannot confirm this.